# Sed : removing lines where pattern result also appears elsewhere

Tags: regex, bash, sed

Let's suppose I have this sample

```
 foo/bar/123-465.txt
 foo/bar/456-781.txt
 foo/bar/102-445.txt
 foo/bar/123-721.txt
```

I want to remove every line where the regex `/[0-9]*-` result also appears on another line. In other terms : I want to remove every line where the file prefix is present more than once in my file.

Therefore only keeping :

```
 foo/bar/456-781.txt
 foo/bar/102-445.txt
```

I bet sed can do this, but how ?

Comment: The above pattern would match all the four lines.

Comment: See my edit, I maybe wasn't clear enough.

Comment: you mean this `sed '/123\-/d' file`?

Comment: Nope. I want to remove duplicate regex result.

Comment: Basically you want to make a group and then say `.match.count > 1`...I don't know if sed can do this but any programming language can. `ruby`, `python`, `c`, `c++`, etc

Comment: I want to remove each line where the prefix is present more than once in the file.

Comment: You are just looking *forward*? Meaning if there are three lines that match the pattern, you want to remove the first and the second, while keeping the third?

Comment: I'm want to keep none of them !

Comment: Do you care about the output order?

Comment: The order is not important :)

Comment: Hi @MatthieuRiegler I fixed my answer, please undo the downvote :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I misunderstood your problem, here's how to do it:

```
grep -vf <(grep -o '/[0-9]*-' file | sort | uniq -d) file
```

In action:

```
 cat file
 foo/bar/123-465.txt
 foo/bar/456-781.txt
 foo/bar/102-445.txt
 foo/bar/123-721.txt

grep -vf <(grep -o '/[0-9]*-' file | sort | uniq -d) file
 foo/bar/456-781.txt
 foo/bar/102-445.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following `awk` script:

*example.awk:*

```
{
  # Get value of interest (before the -)
  prefix=substr($3,0,match($3,/\-/)-1)

  # Increment counter for this value (starting at 0) 
  counter[prefix]++

  # Buffer the current line
  buffer[prefix]=$0
}

# At the end print every line which's value of interest appeared just once
END {
  for(index in counter)
    if(counter[index]==1)
      print buffer[index]
}
```

Execute it like this:

```
awk -F\ -f example.awk input.file
```

Comment: :) look at them, they are different in detail. my solution does not need the lookup `if(store[id])`. However, your usage of `match()` looks nice!

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '
 match($0, "[0-9]*-") {
    id=substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)
    if (store[id])
       dup[id] = 1
    store[id] = $0
 }
 END {
    for(id in store) {
      if(! dup[id]) {
        print store[id]
      }
    }
 }
'
```